# Libreoffice changing all cell references to absolute/relative

Tags: regex, libreoffice

wondering if there is a simple regex or other way to replace a selection of relative reference formulas in a spreadsheet with absolute references.

I had thought of something along the lines of

`search key: =(.*)([A-Z])([0-9])(.*)$`

with

`replace key: =$1\$$2\$$3$4`

But even it that worked it would only replace the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

Search for:

```
(?:(Sheet\d+\.)??([A-Z]{1,2}?)([1-9]+))*
```

Replace with:

```
$1\$$2\$$3
```

**NB**: Running it on a cell or sheet which already has absolute references (which is the same as running the search and replace twice) will screw things up.

Comment: Thank you Duncan. Wonderfully elegant.

Comment: Hi Duncan, had a look at this again and unfortunately it doesnt work with `=Sheet1.B2+Sheet1.C2+SUM(Sheet1.D2:D11)` . It seems to struggle with multi-sheet formulae particularly.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer to handle Sheet references - it's a bit less elegant, but it works.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer, so that other users know that it worked and that the question has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Duncan, completely missed that. Great answer

Comment: there is a mistake in regexp - zeros are not matched

Comment: Do you mean references to rows or columns who have an address of zero? Afaik, rows in libreoffice calc start at 1 (and columns go A,B...)?